# Do damage bonuses apply to spell damage rolls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, spells

When you have bonuses on damage rolls, say, from [power attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#powerAttack), can you apply the damage bonus to spells such as [chill touch](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/chillTouch.htm)?

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be answered in a general way for either game. The question *When a caster touches a creature with the spell* chill touch *can the caster also deal extra damage with Power Attack?* is fine, but *bonuses on damage rolls* means assessing every damage bonus source and *such as chill touch* means assessing every similar spell. If the example in the question *is* the exact circumstance and what you're actually interested in, please, ask *that* question instead of widening the question to other areas!

Comment: If it just says "bonus to melee damage rolls", does it apply to melee spells?

Comment: Suggest you confine this question to Pathfinder, or to 3.5.  That would narrow its scope to allow a correct and specific answer.

Comment: Completely disagree with @KorvinStarmast; this is narrow enough to be answerable, and a good answer can discuss the distinction between the two. The real problem is attempting to nail down a general case when slight wording differences in each case could completely change the answer; it’s really impossible to fully generalize.

Comment: @Kryan Standard template for a question is "what problem are you trying to solve" and typically if you are playing one game system, you aren't playing the other one.  Is the problem to solve in PF or in 3.5?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Actually, Pathfinder is played *with* 3.5 as often as not. That was, after all, originally a major selling point. So problem-solving in some 3.PF variant is a valid scope. Artificially selecting one would separate the question from the actual problem to be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 3.5, *Complete Arcane* defined the concept of “weapon-like spells,” and page 72 discusses the *Player’s Handbook* feats that are eligible for them: Power Attack is not on the list. This implies (but does not state outright) that it does not work with spells.

In Pathfinder, Power Attack explicitly states that it does not function for any kind of touch attack, which would include nearly-all spells. The situation for spells that attack armored AC is left ambiguous.

However, this discusses only the Power Attack feat. The phrase “melee damage rolls” does not indicate any such limitation (and arguably, RAW, the 3.5 *Complete Arcane* implications would be invalid anyway per primary source rules). I would ordinarily read “melee damage rolls” as including the damage rolls resulting from melee touch attack spells.

Comment: I always thought touch spells couldn't be used with the feat Power Attack because touches are, essentially, light weapons (and therefore also eligible for use with the feat Weapon Finesse). Is there any support for that or am I misremembering?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Hmm, that’s an interesting idea; that may very well be true. I would have to reread the relevant material, but I’m away from my books.

Comment: An unarmed attack or natural attack is a light weapon, and if you make an unarmed attack along with a touch spell, then that attack is made with a light weapon, but the touch attack from the touch spell is never given that designation, at least not in 3.5e.

Comment: It is of note that (at least in Pathfinder) you can opt to hold the charge of your touch spell and discharge it with an unarmed strike, targeting full AC. Power attack would be usable with that unarmed strike (though a wizard casting a spell and punching an enemy without IUS might not be wise for their health).

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence of the [Power Attack](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#power-attack) feat in pathfinder:

> You must choose to use this feat before making an attack roll, and its effects last until your next turn. **The bonus damage does not apply to touch attacks or effects that do not deal hit point damage.**

So it doesn't work in pathfinder because it's a touch attack.

Comment: The question is tagged both Pathfinder and 3.5, and this line does not exist in 3.5. This answer is incomplete.

Comment: @KRyan The question, in that case, needs to either be about 3.5 or Pathfinder, not both.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Well, [meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4928/4563) disagrees with you.

Comment: @Kryan And I disagree with meta.  SE model generally requires a well scoped question.  This isn't one.

Comment: I understand why someone would want to know about both settings. But I'll treat it like 2 seperate questions, which I could only awnser one of. That's why I specifically said I was talking about Pathfinder.